# Is there way to select time range for chatbase funnel reports

Tags: chatbase

Can we select time range for funnel reports. Session flow report allows the time selection but I don't see the same option for funnel reports.

Comment: Consider adding some code or extra information

Answer (score 1):

Adding selectable time ranges to the Funnels report is on our roadmap, but not yet available. The list of intents available in the dropdown is the full set of intents that have been received by your bot all time.